# How do you add an ASP.NET web API to the default SERVER ASP.NET Blazor Default Generated Solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-server-side, syncfusion-blazor-sfgrid

What is the best approach to add a web api as a project to the default ASP.NET Blazor solution?
When using visual studio 2019 you no longer get the server and web projects when you select Blazor server on create new solution/project.

I found a way be browsing serveral blogs but it was mentioned that microsoft might dis-continue this.

Looking for the best way.
The reason I need to add an API to an ASP.NET Blazor Side project is to so the SyncFusion DataGrid can bind to it.   See:
https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/datagrid/data-binding/#entity-framework

**Here is what I am thinking of trying:**

Use "options.EnableEndpointRouting" approach.

- Step 1: Create an API folder
- Step 2: Right Click/Add New/
  Controller/Web API Step
- Modify Startup.cs with:

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

Is this considered a future safe or supported way to do it?

Server Side Blazor Created By VS 2019 Wizard:

[image]

Solution generated looks like:
[image]

Comment: For starters, nothing changed in .net5 or VS2019, you still have the same templates. And nothing is announced to be discontinued.

Comment: And I find it hard to decide what "the default ASP.NET Blazor solution" is exactly. Are you talking about Blazor Server-side or about the Server part of Blazor Wasm Hosted?

Comment: As you have tagged this `blazor-server-side` I am curios to what would be the client of the API?

Comment: @BrianParker : The client of the api is actually a SyncFusion Data Grid within the same server side blazor project.  Based on their documentation, they  recommend having a web api "Bind" to the control with all CRUD actions.  For that part of my server side blazor project, I can't bind to a list populated by Entity Framework directly.  I was actually trying to avoid writting an api layer when choosing the blazor server side project and that is what makes it interesting.

Comment: @HenkHolterman:  I am talking about Blazor Server Side only.  See what I just wrote to BrianParker above.  I chose not to do the web assembly specifically so I would not have to write an api layer... Then found I could not bind directly to Entity Framework without a web API Layer for a Sync Fusion Data Grid.

Comment: Sync Fusion Documentation: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/datagrid/data-binding/#entity-framework

Comment: @enet,,, Are you thinking add a totally separate Web API project?

Comment: @enet,  Are you saying make a web api project in the same solution?  I am afraid of the line of code below blowing up my blazor page routing... Also I am concerned about security of the api.  Then having to deal with CORS issues.  I do have little experience.  Are you saying deploy the web api project on the same server as blazor?  Instead of adding a folder /api in the blazor server project... better to add a new Web API to the solution?  If that is the case, do I still have to modify the startup.css to modify routing the same way? Concern--> services.AddMvc(options => ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in touch with Syncfusion Support and they provided a sample of using their data grid to skip the API.

The example at the link below actually has Entity Framework calls right in the Blazor page code.  I implemented with a service wrapping the Entity Framework.

Works great.  Also used this same approach with Dapper.

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/165744/how-to-add-a-supporting-web-api-and-routing-to-support-databinding-in-sf-grid-on-blazor

[image]